# How to Write alter statement to alter Temp Table with Dynamic name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written the following query - what is my fault? Please guide me

```
set @sqlAlter = 'alter table #RD_Temp' + @UserNum + ' add ' + @columnname + ' DECIMAL(18,2)'    
Execute sp_executesql @sqlAlter
```

Here `#RD_Temp'+ @UserNum` is the dynamic name for my temp table and `@UserNum = 1` which is changed as per user and `@columnname` is dynamic column.

I get this error:

> Cannot find the object "#RD_Temp1" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Comment: This looks like an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Add specifics as to why you are creating a dynamic temp table name (and column name). Temp tables are unique per session so different sessions can use the same name and SQL Server uniqueifies the internal name automatically.

Comment: @MissRSMM . . . I have worked with databases for a long time.  I have never had to add a column to a dynamically generated temporary table.  You are asking the wrong question.

Comment: I guess the problem originates from that single-sharp (#) temp tables do not persist over distinct sessions. A double-sharp (##) temp table does persist, but may have side effects: (1)name conflict over different users (2)when to be cleaned up. A more complete context is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly using `#RD_Temp`, you should use `tempdb..#RD_Temp`.

e.g.

```
set @sqlAlter = 'alter table tempdb..#RD_Temp' + @UserNum + ' add ' + @columnname + ' DECIMAL(18,2)'
```